# background: 50% 50% / cover; What does it mean?

Tags: css, background

```
.slide{
    background: 50% 50% / cover; 
}
```

What does `background: 50% 50% / cover` do?

I know background syntax is like this
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

```
body {
    background: #ffffff url("img_tree.png") no-repeat right top;
}
```

But why in my code there is `50% 50% / cover` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A.** `background-position:50% 50%`

the `background-position` has these values `position( left/right/center top/center/bottom) |x% y%|xpos ypos|initial|inherit;`

`background-position:50% 50%` means

> The first value is the horizontal position and the second value is the vertical. The top left corner is 0% 0%. The right bottom corner is 100% 100%. If you only specify one value, the other value will be 50%. . Default value is: 0% 0%

read here more **[background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)**

**B.** `background-size:cover`

the `background-size` property can have these values `background-size: auto|length|cover|contain|initial|inherit;`

`background-size:cover` does this :

> Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area

see here **[background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)**

so in your code :

```
body {
background: #ffffff url("img_tree.png") no-repeat right top;
}
```

`right top` is the `background-position` so `50% 50%` will be in their place.
also you don't have a `background-size` set so it's value is `auto`

if you want to combine the two codes just write like this

```
body {
background: url("img_tree.png") no-repeat 50% 50% / cover #ffffff ;
}
```

Which translates into

```
body {
background-image: url("img_tree.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-size: cover;
background-color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means :background:position/size.

this is a [helpful link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp) where you can find a detailed information about background property

Answer (score 0):

First and second values are background positions for element. And second "Cover" is background size for the element